# trim using sed to get the exact value from curl

Tags: sed, curl, json

I'm getting this string data from `curl` command

`{"password": [["passwordreal", "2035/01/01 00:00"]], "user": "user1", "address": "kobebkokoko.net"}`

How do I get `passwordreal` using `sed`?

Example,

`curl xxxx | sed -n '/ *"password"'` => Been working on this long hours.

Comment: how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Using `jq`, you would get the raw password string with

```
curl ... | jq -r '.password[0][0]'
```

I.e., get the first element of the array-in-array of the `password` key in the returned JSON object.

Using `sed` in this instance would be a mistake, as the password string could possibly contain any character, including JSON encoded data that you would have to decode separately.  `jq` does this for you.